# What button do I have to press in this scene?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

Possible spoiler.

> I got captured and I am stuck on a scene where the bad guy finds my hiding place and drags me out. There is a cinematic and afterwards he chokes me.
>  Here is a picture of the scene: [image]
>  There are two circles and some kind of "call to action" but I cannot figure out what to do.

I tried pressing left click, right click, space etc. with no effect. Either I get the timing wrong or I am pressing the wrong buttons.

I am playing the PC version.

Comment: Odd. It's *supposed* to tell you what button to press. I did read that a lot of PC users had a bug that was causing them not to show, though.

Comment: Yeah in every scene prior to that I got a hint. Like wiggle left and right or press E etc. But here it is just empty.

Comment: There's a way to tell what button you *should* press, but I'm speaking from experience with the PS3. Typically, getting out of a hold is wiggling the left stick; offensive actions (like kicking or biting) is Triangle, which should be whatever is hot-keyed to melee; grabbing onto to something is Square; and alternating L1-R1 is used sparingly (mostly for running sequences). Try to find analogues for PC and you should be good.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. It is "F" or melee action. There is a red exclamation mark (!) for a very short period of time. I thought this was something like: Image or Action missing but it means "melee attack". Checkout "button mappings" "actions" to figure out what symbol refers to each "call to action".

Comment: Actually, the ! means it's a QTE. You should see a different icon (something that looks like an explosion) which is the icon for melee attack (which, as you figured out, is mapped to F by default). I see the icon in my game, so I'm not sure why it isn't showing for you though :S